# Underscan or Overscan

Tags: display

I have been using this monitor (HP24es) since and never had issues. Today, while the monitor was connected and working fine, my MacBook went into sleep mode and when I turned on, this appeared.

[image: Image Picture]

I have tried the following solutions

1. Rebooting Computer with Safe mode and without safe mode
2. Editing /var/db/.com.apple.iokit.graphics file (no option for **pscn** or **oscn**)

What's wrong here?
MacBook Pro 2016 running High Sierra

Comment: Do two things:  1) Try the MacBook with another display and/or TV.  2) Try that monitor with a different computer.  What are the results?

Comment: @Allan
I tried the monitor with another, newer Macbook Pro. It has the same results.
I tried the monitor with a Macbook Pro (older generation without touchpad and which accepts direct HDMI cable), it worked on that without any issues.
I do not have any more displayed to try on.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who lands here after some time, a simple factory reset of my monitor fixed it.